# Quarkus mongodb panache projection not getting the boolean values which starts with "is" Ex: isDeleted

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Quarkus mongodb panache projection not getting the boolean values which starts with "is" Ex: isDeleted
MongoDB:
isDeleted

PanacheEntity:
isDeleted

Projection:
isDeleted

IS there anything we need to take care of these kind of boolean properties.

Comment: It worked post changing the private "isDeleted" to "public deleted". Panache is replacing the deleted with isDeleted while creating the projections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked post changing the private "isDeleted" to "public deleted". Panache is replacing the deleted with isDeleted while creating the projections.